# How to change font size in the title bar of a JDialog

Tags: java, jdialog, titlebar, custom-titlebar

Basically what the title says. I couldn't change the font size of the title bar in a JDialog.

[image: See Image for the problem]

```
 public MyDialog(Frame parent, Bank b) {
        super(parent, "Create Account", true);
        this.bank = b;

        Point loc = parent.getLocation();
        setLocation(loc.x + 420, loc.y + 260);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();        

        setupGUI();
        fieldDataIsOK();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        pack();
    }
```

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to change **only** the font size of the Title Bar. I do not want to change the colour or any other aspect of the title bar. Thanks.